# What's an Early Adapter Access Level in Online Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Here is the new Access Level in Visual Studio "Early Adopter", could anyone explain what is the difference in this as compared to others?

[image]

on Microsoft site, we have below information. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops

Comment: This may help you: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-online-early-adoption-period-extended/